# Fetching from many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Supposed I have a many to many relationship with an intermediate table

```
// one to many relationship with post_tag
post 
 - id
 - title

post_tag
 - post_id
 - tag_id
 - selected

// one to many relationship with post_tag
tag 
 - id
 - name
```

This is the configuration for the relationship of post and tag

```
class Post {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    Set<PostTag> postTag;

    // ...
}

class Tag {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
     Set<PostTag> postTag;

    // ...
}
```

This is for PostTag

```
@Entity
class PostTag {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    Tag tag;

    private String selected;

    // additional properties
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

How can I fetch from post entity to get a response like this?

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "test ttitle",
    "tags" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "test name",
        "post_tag" : {
            "post_id" : 1,
            "tag_id" : 1,
            "selected" : "T"
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how can I start with this? This is my first time using a many to many relationship and I am really confused because on one to many relationship unidirectional with a simple

```
post.findAll()
```

I can get the result with its corresponding relationship with the other table. But on many to many I dont really know where to start specially that there is an intermediate table included

Comment: It's not a many-to-many. If it was, you would use the annotation `ManyToMany`. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. If you load a Post and call getPostTag(), that will give you all its postTags. And if you call getTag() on the PostTags, you will get their Tag (assuming these methods exicts, and assuming PostTag indeed links to Tag and Post, and not to Student and Course as you posted). How you transform this entity graph into JSON is entirely up to you.